# A little question about polite Japanese

Tags: grammar

I can't understand why is it used polite form in -「いらっしゃい。逃げ切れるとは思わないで」, I would translate it like this - "Come! Don't think you can run away!". And as far as I can guess シオン is telling it to an enemy?

```
カイム：「よし、これでこっちの動きは封じた！」 
シオン：「やるわねカイム！さすがあたしの弟！」
カノス：「ちっ、先を越されちまったか！今度はこっちの番だ、頼むぜシオン」 
シオン：「いらっしゃい。逃げ切れるとは思わないで」 
シオン：「Casting some 厨二 spell」 
カノス：「はははははっ！派手にやってくれるぜ！！」
```

Comment: What is so "polite" about that line in the first place?

Comment: @非回答者 The presence of いらっしゃい (which looks like the honorific いらっしゃる) is presumably what makes it seem polite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because シオン and カノス knows each other, and シオン is showing some respect for her enemy, カノス, I guess?

**EDIT:**

(forget my previous answer.)

So カイム, シオン and カノス are friends, and they're trying to disturb and run away from someone not specified here?

Under this context, by "いらっしゃい", シオン is not requesting anything. This does not mean "Come, please," nor "Come on."

Japanese いらっしゃい (or more politely, いらっしゃいませ) can mean "please come," but it usually means "Welcome" or "Glad to see you" or even "Hello (in stores, etc.)". シオン is showing her appreciation for カノス's joining the battle.

Comment: They are friends. They aren't fighting whith each other.

Comment: I think they just fighting with somebody, nobody is running away. That's why I thought that 逃げ切れるとは思わないで is addressed to an enemy.

Comment: So her intention here is the following: "Glad to see you (I appreciate you joining this battle). And don't think we can run away (we, together, have to face this enemy, here and now.)"  Does this make sense?

Comment: Well, maybe... but カノス was a bit upset because カイムkilled one of the enemies before him, that's why he said - 「ちっ、先を越されちまったか！今度はこっちの番だ、頼むぜシオン」. So, I don't think that he wants to run away from enemies.

Comment: If you're really sure that this "いらっしゃい..." was spoken to the enemies, then this can be interpreted as "Welcome (to my territory, attack range, etc.). Don't think you can escape (from my attack spell)."  A very confident killer who enjoys  battles can surely say "welcome", even politely, to her opponents. However this means the third and the fourth lines are not related with each other. Looks like this is from a game scenario, so please double-check what's really shown here.